# Complete Angular Material 2 DataTable Example: Combining Multiple Columns Of Nested Objects To One With Sorting and Filtering

Tags: sorting, datatables, filtering, angular-material2

This is a problem faced during the development of a web application. It had an angular material 2 data table which was rendering data with nested objects and needed to concat data of different columns of nested object in one column. Additionally sorting and filtering on all columns.

Suppose that data is made of the following objects:
Incident, Patient, Doctor that are related. Each Incident is related with a patient and a doctor with a one to many relationship.
So we have the following implementation of objects in typescript:
**Incident.ts**

```
import {Patient} from '../patients/patient';
import {Doctor} from 'app/doctors/doctor';    

export class Incident {

  private _id: number;
  private _protocolNo: number;
  private _date: any;
  private _symperasma: string;
  private _patient: Patient;

  get id(): number {
    return this._id;
  }

  set id(value: number) {
    this._id = value;
  }

  get protocolNo(): number {
    return this._protocolNo;
  }

  set protocolNo(value: number) {
    this._protocolNo = value;
  }

  get date(): any {
    return this._date;
  }

  set date(value: any) {
    this._date = value;
  }

  get symperasma(): string {
    return this._symperasma;
  }

  set symperasma(value: string) {
    this._symperasma = value;
  }

  get patient(): Patient {
    return this._patient;
  }

  set patient(value: Patient) {
    this._patient = value;
  }
}
```

**Patient.ts**

```
import {Incident} from '../incidents/incident';

export class Patient {

  _id: number;
  _firstName: string;
  _lastName: string;
  _incidents: Incident[];

  get incidents(): Incident[] {
    return this._incidents;
  }

  set incidents(value: Incident[]) {
    this._incidents = value;
  }

  get id(): number {
    return this._id;
  }

  set id(value: number) {
    this._id = value;
  }

  get firstName(): string {
    return this._firstName;
  }

  set firstName(value: string) {
    this._firstName = value;
  }

  get lastName(): string {
    return this._lastName;
  }

  set lastName(value: string) {
    this._lastName = value;
  }

}
```

Now lets inspect the DataTables Code. The data is received by an http get request and assigned to a MatTableDataSource in function call **getIncidents()**.

**IncidentsListComponent.ts**

```
export class IncidentsListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  displayedColumns = ['protocolNo', 'date', 'patient.lastName patient.firstName', 'actions'];

  incidentsDataSource: MatTableDataSource<Incident> = new MatTableDataSource<Incident>();

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;    

  constructor(private incidentsService: IncidentsService) {

  }

  async ngOnInit() {
    await this.getIncidents();
    this.incidentsDataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.incidentsDataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
      switch (property) {
        case 'patient.lastName patient.firstName':
          return item.patient.lastName + ' ' + item.patient.firstName;
        case 'protocolNo':
          return item.protocolNo;
        case 'date':
          return item.date;
      }
    };
    this.incidentsDataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.incidentsDataSource.filterPredicate = (data, filter) => JSON.stringify(data).includes(filter);
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.incidentsDataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }

  getIncidents() {
    this.incidentsService.getIncidents().subscribe((results) => {
        this.incidentsDataSource.data = results;
      }
      // )
    );
  }

}
```

In **displayedColumns** array are declared the displayed columns of DataTable where we see the concatenation of two columns in one for patient object data.

For Sorting and Filtering **this.incidentsDataSource.sortingDataAccessor** and **this.incidentsDataSource.filterPredicate** are implemented. In **sortingDataAccessor** there is concatenation of columns again. In **filterPredicate** JSON to string conversion and filtering.

**applyFilter** function is called in template on (keyup) event of input search field as you will see below in the template file. Also at the input field related to patient object we use again concatenation in *matcolumnDef*

**incidents-list.component.html**

```
<!--Filtering input fields-->
<div class="example-header">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput #filter (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Αναζήτηση">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>

<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">

  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="incidentsDataSource" matSort>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="protocolNo">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Αρ. Πρωτοκόλλου</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.protocolNo}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="date">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Ημερομηνία</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.date | date:'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="patient.lastName patient.firstName">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Ασθενής</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.patient.lastName}} {{row.patient.firstName}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Ενέργειες</mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" style="white-space: nowrap">

        <button mat-icon-button (click)="openDialog(row)">
          <span matTooltip="Λεπτομέρειες!">
          <mat-icon style="color: grey">assignment</mat-icon>
          </span>
        </button>

        <a [routerLink]="['./update', row.id]">
          <span matTooltip="Επεξεργασία!">
          <mat-icon>mode_edit</mat-icon>
          </span>
        </a>

        <a [routerLink]="['./delete', row.id]">
          <span matTooltip="Διαγραφή!">
          <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
          </span>
        </a>

        <button mat-icon-button (click)="renderPDF(row.id)">
          <span matTooltip="Λεπτομέρειες!">
          <mat-icon style="color: grey">picture_as_pdf</mat-icon>
          </span>
        </button>

      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>

  </mat-table>

  <mat-paginator #paginator
                 [length]="incidentsDataSource?.filteredData.length"
                 [pageIndex]="0"
                 [pageSize]="25"
                 [pageSizeOptions]="[25, 50, 100, 250, 500]">
  </mat-paginator>

</div>
```